# Find out the rule, then solve it

Tags: mathematics, visual, no-computers, number-theory

First, Find out the rule from the example, 
Then solve the puzzle without computer.
The answer must be unique (just 1 valid answer).

**Example** 
[image]

**Solve This**
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is this it? (Think this is the unique answer)

> [image]

The rule is

> Each set of three (.-. - Two circles at the bottom one at the top inbetween) circles sums to the number at the bottom, and the red dot indicates that two numbers touching it are 1 apart. And obviously only numbers 1-10 are used.

So we have (bold indicates red dot)

> 10+5+1=16
> **5+4+7=16 and 5-4=1**
> **1+7+8=16 and 8-7=1**
> **9+4+3=16 and 4-3=1**
> **3+7+6=16 and 7-6=1**
> 6+8+2=16

How I solved this:

> There are only two possible set of numbers for the two under 10: 4 and 2 or 5 and 1. First I tried out 4 and 2, found it didn't work, and then tried 5 and 1. I quickly found that the numbers worked. From there it was just trial and error.

Comment: In the original, why don't 10-6-4 add to 17?  Or 3-4-5?  That is a group of three circles that doesn't follow your rule.

Comment: @Trenin because the base of the triangle should be 2 circles. They are both inverted. Note my answer says the triangle format looks like .-.

Comment: Ah... thats what that was. I thought it was some ascii smiley that I wasn't familiar with so I ignored it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> S17 = sum of all circle which is connected to Red dot.
>
>  [image]

Comment: Sorry, still wrong.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya :( is rule correct?

Comment: @JamalSenjaya if the rule is correct (which it seems it is) then there are probably multiple answers

Comment: The answer is unique.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya ah, I think I may have it. Don't know what the red dots are for, but I have a different rule which will probably give a unique answer...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil the brown dot is useful to ease the search for the answer.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya think I got it. See my answer